# QODBC connection string format

Tags: mysql, qt, odbc

I am trying to learn about databases and my most current challenge is connecting from my **iOS** machine using **qt5** into a database through the **QODBC** driver. After a bit of goggle-ing sure enough I found a bunch of threads on the subject and I now realise that in order to get rid of my

*"QODBC3: Unable to connect" "[iODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified. Driver could not be loaded"*

error I must specify a connection string like such

```
db->setDatabaseName("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=*<ip/host>*;Database=*<database>*;Uid=*<userid>*;Pwd=*<password>*;"
```

But I still can't make this work, because I am not sure what should I put as a Driver value. Where is this driver, or what if my database server is on another computer inside my Lan?

Comment: Start with setting server, database, credentials... the Driver string is correct for ms-sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The QODBC driver adds a windows DSN. They are quite clever about preventing access from processes not running on the Quickbooks computer unless you buy their $499 server version.

I access the QODBC driver from within PHP command line, I first allow the odbc php module and use this in my PHP script:

```
$qb = odbc_connect("Quickbooks Data", "", "");
```

I did experiment with running a PHP script as a service, connected to a port which would then listen for incoming queries and reply with the result.

This worked, but ultimately we moved Quickbooks out of the workflow we use interacting with customers. Quickbooks is too unreliable for mission critical processes (example: taking money from customers); multiple times something would happen, Windows or UPS would update, and then our automated workflow for shuffling customer data and charging credit cards would fail.